# Simple vernam cryptography

Tags: cryptography

I want to learn vernam encryption.

First of all, can you confirm me that the algorithm is the same for encoding and decoding?

I have read an exercice which say to decode this message with Pi:

```
01237 55235 31127 12189 87479 1592
```

I have tried vernam python pacakge and i tried this:

```
py_vernam.vernam('01237552353112712189874791592','3.141592653589793238462643383')
```

or

```
py_vernam.vernam('01237552353112712189874791592','31415926535897932384626433832')
```

But it does not give me a readable message...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"can you confirm me that the algorithm is the same for encoding and decoding?"

-> first of all, we are talking about encryption not encoding (at the first step) ... the notable difference, to tell those two apart, is that there is a key involved here...

depending on which variant of vernam you are handling, encryption and decryption may be the same or not ... for the binary variant it surely is the same operation, a simple XOR

if you happen to have got your fingers on the "let's do this by hand" or schoolbok variant, it is not, basically because it handles values mod 10 and not mod 2, leading to encryption is + ... decryption is - ...

the notation in blocks of 5 is an indication for the mod 10 variant, since with the mod 2 variant you usually just handle binary data

```
01237552353112712189874791592 Ciphertext
31415926535897932384626433832 Key
========================================
70822636828325880805258368760 Text (encoded)
```

so finally we have to read the encoding into characters... (second step)

it is up to the user of the cipher to give these numbers a meaning so when searching for your example message you can find a french page showing a substitution table... so ... let's have a look ...

Substitution table:

```
Clair       A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z  
Chiffré     6   38  32  4   8   30  36  34  39  31  78  72  70  76  9   79  71  58  2   0   52  50  56  54  1   59
```

Result:

```
70  8   2   2   6   36  8       2   8   32  58  8   0       8   0       52  58  36  8   76  0  
M   E   S   S   A   G   E       S   E   C   R   E   T       E   T       U   R   G   E   N   T
```